# Retaining a value for all observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set that looks like the following but with multiple patients:

```
ID   Variable   val    Visit  
A     Height     5     Base
A     Weight     3     Base
A     BMI        1     Base
A     Height     2    Visit 1
A     Weight     4    Visit 1
A     BMI        3    Visit 1

data have;
input id    var $   val visit $;
cards;
A height 5 base
A weight 3 base
A bmi 1 base
A height 2 visit1
A weight 4 visit1
A bmi 3 visit1
;
```

I would like to create a 3 new columns that retains the base value for all visits:

```
 ID   Variable  Value   Visit    Height   Weight   BMI 
 A     Height     5     Base       5        3      1    
 A     Weight     3     Base       5        3      1 
 A     BMI        1     Base       5        3      1 
 A     Height     2    Visit 1     5        3      1  
 A     Weight     4    Visit 1     5        3      1    
 A     BMI        3    Visit 1     5        3      1
```

I would attempt this by retaining the "base" value but I'm a bit stumped on how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc sort data=mydata out=base;
  where visit='base';
  by id;
run;

data base;
  set base;
  by id;

  if first.id then call missing(weight, height, bmi);
  retain height weight bmi;
  if var = 'Height' then height = val;
  else if var = 'Weight' then weight = val;
  else bmi = val;

  if last.id then output;
  keep height weight bmi id;

run;

proc sql;
  create table withbase as
  select * from mydata a full join base b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Hi! I hope I'm not mistaking anything but I received an error for the proc sql step: ERROR: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name a. How can I fix this to get my desired output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Sorry to bother again but I seem to be unable to run it. Perhaps there is something I've missed? I have added sample code in my query section if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: I did not use the exact same variable names in my code. Did you make the necessary changes?

Comment: Yes, I changed VALUE to val and changed the cases to match which I've reflected in sample code. Please let me know if there's anything else I can fix.

Comment: Can you share the log please

Comment: I've added the log to the main query leaving out any notes on cpu run time etc. Please let me know if there's anything else.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the errors, but my output is not as expected. The coloumns weight, height and bmi are empty:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQiyI.png

Answer (score 1):

Adding BASELINE to every obs as you are asking for doesn't seem very useful.  How about something like this.

```
data have;
input id:$1. var $ val visit $;
cards;
A height 5 base
A weight 3 base
A bmi 1 base
A height 2 visit1
A weight 4 visit1
A bmi 3 visit1
;;;;
   run;
proc sort data=have;
   by id var visit;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data maybe;
   do until(last.var);
      set have;
      by id var;
      if visit eq 'base' then baseline=val;
      if not missing(baseline) then do;
         change = val - baseline;
         end;
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]